# Weird behaviour with abstract method TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use typescript with the reference "atmosphere.d.ts" [source here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/atmosphere/atmosphere.d.ts). I trigged a strange behaviour with abstract methods which leads to the error :

> TypeError: this.protectedMethod is not a function

Here is the typescript code :

```
/// <reference path="../atmosphere.d.ts" />
import Request = Atmosphere.Request;

abstract class AbstractRequest {

    // The atmosphere request
    protected socket: Request;

    // Here we initialize the socket
    protected init(url: string): void {
        this.socket = {
            url                 : "http://localhost:9000/" + url,
            contentType         : "application/json",
            transport           : "websocket" ,
            fallbackTransport   : "long-polling"
        };

        /* SOME CODE */

        this.socket.onOpen = function(response) {
            this.protectedMethod();
        };
    }

    // Some protected method called in this.socket.onOpen
    protected abstract protectedMethod(): void;
}

class Registration extends AbstractRequest {

    // Implementation of the abstract method
    protected protectedMethod(): void {
        console.log("hello");
    }
}
```

Without error, the folllowing javascript code is generated :

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
};
var AbstractRequest = (function () {
    function AbstractRequest() {
    }
    // Here we initialize the socket
    AbstractRequest.prototype.init = function (url) {
        this.socket = {
            url: "http://localhost:9000/" + url,
            contentType: "application/json",
            transport: "websocket",
            fallbackTransport: "long-polling"
        };
        /* SOME CODE */
        this.socket.onOpen = function (response) {
            this.protectedMethod();
        };
    };
    return AbstractRequest;
}());
var Registration = (function (_super) {
    __extends(Registration, _super);
    function Registration() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    // Implementation of the abstract method
    Registration.prototype.protectedMethod = function () {
        console.log("hello");
    };
    return Registration;
}(AbstractRequest));
//# sourceMappingURL=test.js.map
```

I can't call the abstract method (may be non abstract either?) from the "socket" variable when I implement the "onOpen" method. The only workaround I found for now, is to instantiate a global variable

```
var registration = new Registration();
```

and then :

```
this.socket.onOpen = function(response) {
    registration.protectedMethod;
};
```

With this workaround, I have to define "protectedMethod" public. Is there an explanation to this behaviour, and a workaround/fix? Btw, I use typescript 1.8.10

Thanks,

Comment: I believe that is actually expected of protected methods. They are only exposed to its own class and sub classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [the way that `this` works in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method):

```
var AbstractRequest = (function () {
    function AbstractRequest() { }
    AbstractRequest.prototype.init = function (url) {
        // ...snip...
        this.socket.onOpen = function (response) {
            this.protectedMethod();
        };
    };
    return AbstractRequest;
}());
```

When you call `new AbstractRequest().socket.onOpen()` `this` will be bound to `socket` not to `new AbstractRequest()` (`this` points to whatever is on the left of the dot).

You can use an arrow function to work around this. Within arrow functions `this` is bound to the context it was defined in, not the context it is being run in:

```
this.socket.onOpen = response => {
    this.protectedMethod();
};
```

Comment: Really interesting, thanks for the tip and the explanation !

Comment: No problem. MDN is a good source if you'd like more detail. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method

Comment: But isn't it a bug not report that the method doesn't exist since it is out of the scope ?

Comment: More of a missing feature. There's been some work to implement a `--noImplicitThis` flag which would detect this bug. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6739.